# Failed to load resource socket.io in nodejitsu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, nodejitsu

I'm trying to deploy a simple chat applicacion in Nodejitsu, and using socket.io.

I use the application localy and it works perfectly but when I deploy to nodejitsu I get the following error in the javascript console:

> Failed to load resource

And the chat doesnt work.

I checked to the source code and clicked in the

> /socket.io/socket.io.js

and it works perfectly

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "Chat_1",
  "subdomain": "Chat_1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0-4",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "*"
  }
}
```

I hope someone could help me, please!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Nodejitsu Handbook "We reroute all traffic to port 80". Double check you're using port 80.

```
server.listen(80);
```